# Android: populate a popup spinner

Tags: android, popup, android-spinner

I'm new to Android, and I'm struggling with this problem: I want to have a popup spinner populated with elements from one of my arrays.
The code in the main activity is:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater adbInflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View SpinnerLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
adb2.setView(SpinnerLayout);
adb2.setTitle("Select destination");

Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ListPointName);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
adb2.show();
```

And my spinner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >  
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this code, I have a fatal exception:

```
01-05 17:45:07.273: E/AndroidRuntime(8093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

(but if I run it without the ArrayAdapter part, I have my popup spinner empty, so the problem should be when I try to fill the spinner…
I checked, and my list ListPointName is not empty.)

Can someone explain please what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can u please provide complete stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this-

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

do this-

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) SpinnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to find the view from your main layout, but your spinner is in spinnerLayout, So

Change `Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);` to `Spinner s = (Spinner) SpinnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);`